# Printing the largest 3 numbers

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at c++ and have hit a wall in this problem. I know I'm a few lines off from making this program work, but I have tried everything I could. I know it has to do with the assignments after the "else" statement. I would appreciate the help.

I have to make a program where you enter 10 numbers, and in the end it prints out the largest 3 of the 10 numbers. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
int biggest;
int second;
int third;
int number;
int c;
biggest=0, second=0;
cout<<"Enter 10 numbers: ";
for(c=0;c<=9;c++) {
    cin >>number;
    if(number>biggest) {
        third=second;
        second=biggest;
        biggest=number;
    }else{
        second=number;
        if(number<=second)
            third=second;
    }
}
cout<< "Largest number is: " << biggest << " second largest number is: " <<second <<" third largest is: " << third <<endl;
```

Thank you!

Comment: in your if statement you need to compare with all three values, at the moment you compare only the first. the else statement basically just replaces the second and third value with the same value.

Comment: An easier solution would be to accept ten numbers into an array, sort them in descending order, and print the first 3.

Comment: @wallyk No need to do complete sort, it's enough to quick-partition until the third item is found. Then the two bigger will be just before the third one (and the rest of array may stay unordered).

Comment: @CiaPan:  Well, by "easier" I meant just call `qsort()`.  The compare function is a one liner, so a full array sort takes 2 lines.  AFAIK, an interrupted quick sort will requires 15+ lines.

Comment: @wallyk: Instead of `std::sort`, use `std::partial_sort`: no more lines.

Answer (score -1):

link: http://ideone.com/4P8AX0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec;
    int value = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cin >> value;
        vec.push_back(value);
    }

    std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());

    cout << "biggest" << vec[9] << endl;
    cout << "2nd biggest" << vec[8] << endl;
    cout << "3rd biggest" << vec[7] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

whole program enjoy

Comment: As mentioned in comment, `std::partial_sort` is sufficient.

Comment: Note that your algorithm is `O(N)` in memory whereas OP's code is `O(1)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 suppose in future he/she want to extend this loop from 10 to 10000 and want to print top 100 he is not gona have these if else game for 100 time and yes of course with 100 diff variables too :P.

Comment: There is still possibility to be `O(1)` (in memory), but the algorithm should be smarter than the current one (using `std::lower_bound` for example).

Comment: but std::lower_bound need partial ordering otherwise it's like moving one by one.. if i am not wrong?

Comment: I mean that you may keep a sorted array of the current 100 biggest numbers, and then insert new number to the right position (and discard the 101th element).